# How to use a middleware inside a controller function (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to add a middleware that checks the object schemas of the `request.body` :

if the test checks, continue with the controller fonction through `next()`
if the test doesn't check,  continue with the error handling middleware through `next(error)`

The middleware works fine, however I would like to add it at the beginning of the function that needs it instead of adding it in the route for the sake of practicality and curiosity.

I'm getting the error: "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client", while I do not use response in the middleware, I wonder if it is possible to integrate it in a function or not at all?

Many thanks !

List Controller (app/controllers/list.controller.js)

```js
 updateListById: async function (request, response, next) {
        validateList(request.body, next);

        const { position, name } = request.body;
        const { id } = request.params;

        try {
            const list = await List.findByPk(id);
            list.name = name;
            list.position = position;
            await list.save();

            response.json(list);
        } catch (error) {
            console.trace(error);
            next(error);
        }
    },
```

List Validator (app/validator/list.validator.js)

```js
const z = require("zod");
const validateData = require("../utils/validateData");

const schemaData = z.object({
    name: z.string().min(2, { message: "Le nom doit faire au moins deux caractères." }),
    position: z.number({ message: "Veuillez remplir la position." }),
});

const listValidator = {
    validateList: function (listData, next) {
        return validateData(listData, schemaData, next);
    },
};

module.exports = listValidator;
```

Data Validator (app/utils/validateData.js)

```js
function validateData(data, schema, next) {
    const z = schema.parse(data);
    if (z.errors) return next(errors);
    next();
}

module.exports = validateData;
```